# How from Bash script (running as root or a superuser/sudo) to check sudoers file if a user can SUDO

Tags: bash

I need to check from bash script (running with root priveledges) if another user is question can execute sudo as a dedicaite permission via 'username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' in sudoers.

simple command run from a user in question easily returns 1 or 0:

```
sudo -n uptime 2>&1|grep 'load'|wc -l
```

but it always returns as **empty** if I change the user within script:

```
sudo -i -u username bash <<EOF
CAN_I_RUN_SUDO="$(sudo -n uptime 2>&1|grep 'load'|wc -l)"
echo "$CAN_I_RUN_SUDO"
whoami
EOF
```

Here is my full script:

```
sudo -i -u username bash <<EOF
whoami
CAN_I_RUN_SUDO="$(sudo -n uptime 2>&1|grep 'load'|wc -l)"
echo "$CAN_I_RUN_SUDO"
EOF
if [ ${CAN_I_RUN_SUDO} -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "I can run the Sudo command. No need to change sudoers"
else
    echo "I can't run the Sudo command. Added to Sudoers."
    sh -c "echo \"username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL\" >> /etc/sudoers"
fi
```

However, $CAN_I_RUN_SUDO is always returns **empty** (rather then 0 or 1) when I run it as a script. :-( so condition always fails.

I obviously missing something, but can't see it. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of grepping for output, you may be able to just check the return value of `sudo`:

```
if sudo -i -u username sudo -n uptime 2>&1; then
    echo "I can run the Sudo command. No need to change sudoers"
else
    echo "I can't run the Sudo command. Added to Sudoers."
    echo "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
fi
```

If I may, my unrelated security advice would be to avoid automatically adding users to the sudoers file.

Comment: Thank you, but your example has a syntax error. It throughs the following: sudo: update: command not found
I can't run the Sudo command. Added to Sudoers.
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected... Also command 'sudo -i -u username sudo -n update 2>&1' run as stand alone does not work either throughing "sudo: update: command not found". Ubuntu 18.04 with latest updates...

Comment: @uzla, sorry, it should be `uptime`, not `update`. Regarding the syntax error, I believe that the error is from your own question, as I copy-pasted that line and I now see that it's missing a quote.

Comment: It might, in fact, not be missing a quote. It's not clear to me why you're passing it through `sh`, though.

Comment: Just use `echo "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers` without `sh -c`